# Could not install Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to install java on a Linux machine. I downloaded the file via `wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u72-b14/jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Then i tried the following command:

> tar zxvf jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now [root@localhost ~]#

Can someone tell me how to install java on a Linux machine ? I get the above error, and i have no clue how to resolve it.

Comment: How big is the file. There are sometimes problems with using wget from oracle because they insist that you need to accept the license before downloading.

Comment: For Oracle Java...take a look here:http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: Here is the official Java documentation on installing. You should follow the instructions. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml

Comment: try installing it from the terminal using apt-get(Ubuntu) or whatever suits your platform, its a better alternative

Comment: I am new to Linux can you show me how to do this ?

Comment: How about trying `tar xvf` instead?

Comment: It's much easier to get it added to the repository...so he can update it when a new version comes out.

Comment: I think you went to the download page in your browser, you selected the download url and pasted that in a wget command, right ? As a result you did not accept the download licence of oracle and you are redirected to this page: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html. As a result you saved the html data as a .tar.gz file which is not in a gzip format. Download the jdk via the normal webpage on a linux box, or download it on your windows pc and copy the binary file (with scp?) to your linux box.

Comment: Ok i got it downloaded. And i used the command `tar xzvf jre-7u72-linux-i586.tar.gz `. Still i am not able to get a result when i type `java -version`. How can i install Java  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Centos and send this on Putty:

```
yum install java7
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but IT WORKS. Up vote for you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded file might get corrupted. You may need to download it again. 
You can check its header by typing

$ **file jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz**

The command should return something like "gzip compressed data".
Also, you may try to check the file integrity by

$ **gzip -t jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz**